# Deserializing models and related models

Tags: django, django-models, deserialization

I'm using `django-reversion` to store history of certain models. Some of these versioned models have "one to many" or "many to many" relations between them. `django-reversion` is properly configured to "follow" relations, so that all models are stored in the same revision.

I don't need to saved restore versions, I just need to be able to deserialize the models stored in a given revision and call a method on one of the deserialized models (for instance `deserialized_model.object.get_summary()`). Problem is that the method accesses related objects, and the related objects being used are the objects currently in database, and not the deserialized objects. I am deserializing all models I need at the same time.

Is there any way to make deserialized model instances use deserialized related model instances instead of actual instances? Note that this is not a `django-reversion` issue, it's more on the Django side.

**EDIT:**

I tried deceiving Django with `prefetch_related`. The idea was to store the deserialized objects as prefetched results, so that the related managers would retrieve objects from there and not from the database. Still no luck.

Comment: have you opened an issue on the github project?

Comment: Nope, I'm hoping someone's done something like this in the past, waiting for some answers, will open a ticket if nothing pops up.

Comment: @dnozay You are welcome to post an aswer with that comment, bounty expires in three days and it would be a shame if I can't award it to anyone. Even if the answer is not what I expect, it's a valid answer.

Comment: @dnozay I am almost convinced, after lots of attempts, that there is neither no easy or nice way to do this at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, the most complete answer to the question is: It is not possible to make deserialized model instances use other deserialized model instances as related objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue tracker for `django-reversion`:
https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/issues

I would start there as the project owner may not be monitoring SO. You may also get answers from the ~90 contributors or ~60 watchers there.